# How does <script type="text/javascript"> and </script> affect timing?

Tags: javascript

I just added SnapEngage to a client's site with the following chunk of code provided by SnapEngage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//www.snapengage.com/snapabug.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SnapABug.addButton("1ff63c0c-0bf1-43e2-b9ae-08de517f08dc","0","55%");
</script>
```

I thought it was weird to have `</script>` and `<script type="text/javascript">` in the middle so I took them out, but then the code stopped working. Why is that? Do they affect timing somehow?

Comment: Wait, so you removed the script contents entirely? did you put them in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496646/how-does-the-location-of-a-script-tag-in-a-page-affect-a-javascript-function-tha?rq=1

Comment: This is interesting, it highlights how browsers parse scripts. Best guess is that when you remove the separators, the browser parsing the container script first, and attempting to call SnapABug.addButton, -then- it's handle the document.write. That's a guess though.

Answer (score 5):

The first script puts `script` tag into HTML which loads `snapabug.js` and loading this resource is **synchronous**. So executing next scripts, which is `SnapABug.addButton(...)`, is suspended until the resource will be downloaded and interpreted. This way, `SnapABug` object is visible in the following scripts.

If you put all JavaScript code in one `script` tag, it is executed as one batch. There is no `SnapABug` object in global scope because the provided script has not been downloaded yet.

Comment: Was hoping someone would know how to explain this