# Javascript inside an html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a pretty simple query here. I have a view page with an div and a form element. This is how they look.

```
<div id="candy" value="valueOfCandy" ></div>

<input type="text" value="javascript:document.getElementById('candy').getAttribute('value')"/>
```

I need to access the value of candy inside input's attribute (it can be any attribute).

I tried the code as I have shown above but that didnt work. I researched on StackOverflow too but couldnt find anything satisfactory. Please help out.

Edit: Thank you everyone. I found the answer to that, which I am gonna mark. Also, deleting this question so that it doesnt confuse someone else.

Comment: That won't work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will save you much pain an misery. Never put JavaScript in HTML, outside of a script tag. Ever.

Comment: Why do you need to do this inside the element? Why not set the value outside of the element?

Comment: And no need for `javascript:` label ever

Comment: Perhaps you mean `<input type="text" onfocus="this.value=document.getElementById('candy').getAttribute('value')" value="mouseover me"/>`

Comment: *"I need to access the value of candy inside input's attribute (it can be any attribute)."* **When** do you need to do that? Why do you think you need to do it in the markup? What about when the user changes the value? I think you have an [X/Y problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also note that `value` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements; if you need to embed your own data in attributes, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: `I tried the code` Unfortunately you tried no code, there is no code here.

Answer (score 4):

If I assume you want to do this at page load, do it like this

*Note 1, custom attributes should have a `data-` prefix and use `.dataset` to access its value.*

*Note 2, for older browsers like IE10 and below, you need `getAttribute` (as in 2nd sample below).*

Stack snippet 1

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy"></div>

<input id="candy2" type="text" value="" />

<script>
  document.getElementById('candy2').value =
  document.getElementById('candy').dataset.value
</script>
```

---

Stack snippet 2

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy"></div>

<input id="candy2" type="text" value="" />

<script>
  document.getElementById('candy2').value =
  document.getElementById('candy').getAttribute('data-value')
</script>
```

Comment: `div` elements don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Correct, and where did I used that?

Comment: In your `div` tag?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No, take a look again...`candy2` is an `input`, the `div` use `getAttribute`

Comment: It doen't matter how you are extracting the data. `value` is invalid on a `div`. The HTML is invalid. `getAttrbute()` doesn't care about validity.

Comment: Yes, although it might work.  custom attributes should start with `data-`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You are correct, I've updated my answer

Comment: And, now that your HTML is valid, you should be using `.dataset` to extract a `data-*` attribute (even though `.getAttribute()` works).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks...keeps me on my toes :) ... answer updated

Comment: @ScottMarcus  That's interesting, getAttribute is of course more compatible with older browsers,.. Is there any link to why `.dataset` should be used instead?.

Comment: @Keith https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @Keith See my answer for the links to the documentation. But, `.dataset` has been standard for several years now (part of HTML5). It's not new.

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I understand all that, but I'm struggling to see where using `getAttribute` should be avoided.  From the link @LGSon posted, it's just a nice wrapper for accessing `data-` attributes.   If it's just for nicer coding, I can understand that.  But just worried it was a depreciated option to use `getAttribute` etc.

Comment: Datasets are not compatible with IE10 - getAttribute is compatible with all browsers currently worth supporting

Comment: @Keith It's not deprecated as `.getAttribute()` is a standard DOM API and is needed for a variety of other attribute access. It's simply the correlating API to `data-*`. As I said, `getAttribute()` works.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks...added a note about that

Comment: @ScottMarcus `you should be using` yeah, it was maybe just the wording that got me worried.  Maybe `you could use`, would have not frightened me so much.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it in JavaScript outside of code but after the objects exist.

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```js
var candy = document.getElementById('candy').getAttribute('data-value');

document.getElementById('input').value = candy;
```

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy" ></div>
    
<input id="input" type="text"/>
```

As mentioned in the comments, please make sure your JavaScript code is loaded after your markup. There are various ways to do this, including waiting for the dom to load.

See [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) and [How does the location of a script tag in a page affect a JavaScript function that is defined in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496646/how-does-the-location-of-a-script-tag-in-a-page-affect-a-javascript-function-tha) for more information.

Comment: What do you mean what event? There is no mention of an event in the post.

Comment: @mplungjan: That's a flaw in Stack Snippets (which I reported years ago, but SE didn't care), not in the answer. When you run the snippet, it has them in the correct order.

Comment: @mplungjan, the snippet works. This isn't a question about where to put the JavaScript code. The order is how the snippet system on stackoverflow adds the different sections.

Comment: @mplungjan stack snippets place `<script>` tag at end of `<body>` with no event wrapper. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: Trying to explain execution of scripts against HTML might be more useful outside a stack snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
document.getElementById('input').value =  document.getElementById('candy').dataset.value
```

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy" ></div>
<input id="input" type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not how you should be doing this.**

JavaScript should be separated out of the HTML completely to avoid a whole host of issues. Including JavaScript in the HTML as you are attempting is a 20+ year old technique that was used before we had standards.

Next, a `div` element can't have a `value` attribute. `value` is only for form fields. But, you can create a **[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** attribute, which allows for you to create custom attributes. You can then extract that value using the **[`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** property.

See below:

```js
// This code would be placed inside of <script> and </script> tags and the whole 
// thing would be placed just before the closing body tag (</body>).
document.getElementById("result").value = document.getElementById('candy').dataset.value;
```

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy"></div>

<input type="text" id="result">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that code either within a script tag or in a separated js file.

Further, always bind the event `DOMContentLoaded` when you need to manipulate DOM elements.

### [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

> The [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event load should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

This way, your logic is totally consistent.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

  document.getElementById('candy2').value =
    document.getElementById('candy').getAttribute('value')
});
```

```html
<div id="candy" value="valueOfCandy"></div>
<input id="candy2" type="text" value="" />
```

A recommendation is to use [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) because the value attribute is related to form fields:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

  document.getElementById('candy2').value =
    document.getElementById('candy').dataset.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="candy" data-value="valueOfCandy"></div>
<input id="candy2" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: *always bind the event DOMContentLoaded when you need to manipulate DOM elements* Actually, if you just place the code at the end of the `body`, you get the correct timings, with less code and less memory usage, so *always* isn't really recommended.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the usage of `DOMContentLoaded` is totally recommended to avoid any problem is future changes in the HTML's structure.  It's a **must-have** because just putting that code (javascript) at the bottom of body is not enough.